# Is Centralized Pipeline Management compatible with Opensearch?

Tags: logstash, opensearch

Is Centralized Pipeline Management compatible with Opensearch?

ref: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/8.2/logstash-centralized-pipeline-management.html#_pipeline_behavior

It mentions that "The pipeline configurations and metadata are stored in **Elasticsearch**". In my case I use **Opensearch**.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not, check the first note in the documentation link you shared.

> Centralized pipeline management is a **subscription feature**. If you want to try the full set of features, you can activate a free 30-day trial. To view the status of your license, start a trial, or install a new license, open the Kibana main menu and click Stack Management > License Management. For more information, see https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions and License Management.

To use this feature you need one of the paid Elastic licenses.

Comment: What would be the equivalent feature in opensearch, if there is one.

Comment: I do not use Opensearch, but I don't think that there is an equivalent yet.

Answer (score 0):

opensearch has no such option to manage the logstash pipeline